# Как в WordPress сделать, чтобы при редактировании фотографии и описания, менялись одновременно на двух страницах?

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть сайт школы на WordPress, где на главной странице есть две превью(фотография) и короткое описание преподавателей с ссылкой "далее", которые ведут на отдельную страницу преподавателя. Как сделать, чтобы при редактировании фотографии и описания (на отдельных страницах), автоматически менялась превью и короткое описание на главной странице ???

Comment: Может проще менять "фотографию" в медиатеке?  https://wordpress.org/plugins/enable-media-replace/ в помощь

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете получить превью конкретной записи по id. https://wp-kama.ru/function/get_the_post_thumbnail

```
echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $size, $attr );
```

Где $post_id - это id post'а, нужной вам страницы